# How to test whether an infinite sum has converged up to a tolerance

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have a function F(x) that is an infinite sum that I know converges. I want to evaluate F(x) for a certain value of x and I have a tolerance.
To give an example, let's say I have a formula for pi expressed as infinite series as the following:

[image]

And let's imagine, I have no idea what pi is! I want to use this infinite series to determine pi , let's say for ten decimal places (or within 0.01% of the exact value), is there any algorithm that will allow me to decide when to stop?

I have posted this question before. People have downvoted it and I deleted it. Hope I have expressed my question properly this time.

Comment: If the terms alternate in sign then the next term is a bound on the error, but there is no general method. If you look at the argument that tells you that any particular series converges there may be information there.

Comment: What you are looking for is often called a modulus of convergence, a function that given $\epsilon > 0$ tells you how far have to go to be within $\epsilon$ of the limit. There are convergent sequences of rational numbers called [Specker sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specker_sequence) that provably have no computable modulus of convergence. So we can prove that there is no general algorithm to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Ethan Bolker forgot the condition that the absolute values of an alternating sequence should be decreasing, for the next term to serve as a bound on the error. More generally, your best bet is to find a bounding series whose tails you can compute. I.e. some series $\sum_n b_n$ for which, if $F = \sum_n f_n$, then you know for all $n, |f_n| \le b_n$, and further, you can calculate $\sum_{n > k} b_n$ for each $k$. Then you find $N$ such that $\sum_{n>N} b_n$ is less than your tolerance, and you will be okay to calculate $F(x) \approx \sum_{n \le N} f_n(x)$.